# Changes in Magento do not take effect

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a magento project which is in remote server. I have admin access to the website and to the source code. The problem is that when i make changes to the php pages in my code, they do not take effect in the website even when i clear the magento cache from backend. I'm relatively new on magento so maybe i there an option in backend to prevent changes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you restarted apache (or nginx, or whatever your web server runs?)

Comment: Well can you share the exact problem over here?